# Ruby extract Hash values and save to new Hash

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

This ia a real ruby newbie question. I have a Hash that looks like this

```
@hash1 = {1=>{"a"=>1,"b"=>2,"c"=>3}}
```

I want to extract the value and store it in a new Hash like this

```
{"a"=>1,"b"=>2,"c"=>3}
```

I tried doing

```
@hash2 = @hash1.values
```

But that gave me an Array that looked like

```
[{"a"=>1,"b"=>2,"c"=>3}]
```

I couldn't figure out how to convert that to a Hash. I'm probably missing something really simple. Any ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple. Just do what you did, but with `[0]` stuck on the end (get first element):

```
@hash.values[0] #=> {"a"=>1,"b"=>2,"c"=>3}
```

Comment: To make it slightly more readable, you can do: `@hash.values.first #=> {"a"=>1,"b"=>2,"c"=>3}`

Answer (score 2):

A bit different approach is to use the exact key that you're looking for:

```
@hash1 = {1=>{"a"=>1,"b"=>2,"c"=>3}}
@hash2 = @hash1[1]
```

Now variable `@hash2` will contain `{"c"=>3, "b"=>2, "a"=>1}`